# Escape characters in WebApi call

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have this very weird issue in that I cannot post over any text with a period in it. Here's the url for my ajax call:

```
url = 'BIReports/SaveReport/' + reportDescription;
```

If reportDescrption has a period in it, it doesnt post. Ideas?

Comment: Let me revise this a bit. If it ends with a period, its doesnt post. It can have a period anywhere in the text except at the very end. Don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx), you may want to try setting `relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping` to `true`.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you're concatenating a string straight into the URL like that, it would also be wise to use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode to avoid issues with special characters - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx - Note that "." is *not* a special character, the above answer by Maggie Ying is still the answer to *that* issue.