# WebApi with backslash (%2f) in ID parameter causes 404 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a WebAPI method with a parameter containing a / (%2f).  If I call this with a parameter without this character it works fine.

Following advice in this link [Escape characters in WebApi call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823509/escape-characters-in-webapi-call) I tried the following, but it hasn't made any difference.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
```

The code i am using to call the WebAPI method is below

```
var id = "AA/F1"; // This causes a problem of 404 not found
var workingId = "BB-F2"; // This works fine
using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip}))
{
    var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://[testServer]/[Controller]/Get/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(id)));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = client.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnType>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());

    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
}
```

I only have one route configured - as so:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

I have also tried hitting it directly using Fiddler and get the same error.

Comment: share the actual url. I think the issue is that you'd need to have the url be 

http://server/users?id=AA%2fF1

vs what i'm guessing you're getting

http://server/users/AA/F1

Comment: I didn't even think of trying that! thanks, it works fine.  However surely part of the routing should allow that? Certainly it works with an ID without a forward slash using controller/action/id...

Comment: the issue is the routing is assuming that you are pointing to a different route with the forward slash in there, and can't find that specific route. With specifying that the parameter is id, it should at that point look for the route with the users/id mapping, and everything from the = to the next ampersand is that parameter value

Answer (score 2):

You can try  `var id = "AA%2fF1";`

**Update:**

You can also use Base64 encoding, something similar to this:

```
var id = "AA/F1";
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id);
var encodedId = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I took care of that with the WebUtility.UrlEncode

Answer (score 1):

You can encode the full url before sending it

```
WebUtility.UrlEncode(string.Format("http://[testServer]/[Controller]/Get/{0}", id))
```

check if this helps

Comment: He is actually encoding the parameter: `var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://[testServer]/[Controller]/Get/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(id)));`